# Unable to edit C# code in Views while debugging using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I have been testing single version of Visual Studio 2015 (from the first CTP to CTP6), and while it's nice, the one thing that bugs me the most is that I am no longer able to edit C# code within views while debugging. I am able to copy paste code in, but once it's in, I can't delete it or change it unless I break all threads or stop debugging.

I've not found anything on Google or MSDN forums - hopefully someone here may know why.

Has this feature been disabled until the full release of VS2015, is it buggy, or is it related to my setup? I've tried running in safe mode, reinstalling, etc. I've tried it on numerous PCs, all with the same result.

Comment: This feature is called *edit and continue*. Apparently, it _is_ enabled in VS 2015: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/12/11/better-together-c-6-and-the-visual-studio-2015-debugger.aspx. Can't you find it in the **Options > Debugging > Edit and Continue** menu?

Comment: @I19 Your comment meets the question. But disabling Edit and Continue does exactly what it says if you like **to edit C# code within controllers while debugging**. In my opion it's a bad deal!

Comment: Edit and Continue is a different story - while it works, it requires breaking all threads, editing the code, and resuming them after. With VS2013, you can easily edit any part of the View (cshtml) file , including code within it without having to break. VS2015 prevents me from editing any code inside the cshtml file while debugging.

Comment: Yes indeed, that's the first thing I noticed on VS2015.
You can edit and save any line of Razor files in VS2013, save and reload on browser seamless, if you break C# code on razor file it will just show an error page when you reload the browser.
Maybe razor is no longer JIT compiled in VS2015?

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been fixed in Visual Studio 2015 RC. Seems it was disabled (either on purpose or temporarily because it wasn't complete in the CTP)